# Get web service response data

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I have made this so far. It's code that will make a json String request with an http Header. When i run this code i get no errors. But i get a Expression result unused warning. I should get a response from the web service after sending this http header.

code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *nid = @"";
    NSString *vocab = @"";
    NSString *inturl = @"testoverview";
    NSString *mail = @"chh@fbr.dk";
    NSString *md5pw = @"4d57e7ef1b7c3f431aca424764e9d786";

    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    nid, @"nid", 
                                    vocab, @"vocab",
                                    inturl, @"inturl",
                                    mail, @"mail",
                                    md5pw, @"md5pw",nil];
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if (!jsonData) {
        NSLog(@"Got an error; %@", error);
            } else if(jsonData) {

                NSString *url = @"http://www.taenk.dk/services/mobile";
                NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed timeoutInterval:30.0];

                [request setValue:jsonString forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-FBR-App"];
                [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]; <-- this line triggers the warning: "Expression result unused"

                NSLog(@"jsonString %@", jsonString);

            }
```

Can anybody clarify 2 things for me:

1. Does this trigger a response as soon as the request to the web service?
2. If yes, how do i print this result out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the result to a variable like

```
NSURLConnection *con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:...
```

for later use (e.g. `[con cancel];`)

Then you should at least implement the delegate method `connection:didFailWithError:`. In the class reference I don't see the `connection:didFinishLoading...` anymore. Can you use the `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` instead, then you'll have the result, be it positive or negative.

This is how I retrieved the data (this version is without ARC):

```
- (void) connection :(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveData :(NSData *)data {
    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    [self checkAutoMailReply:msg];
    [msg release];
}
```

`msg` contains the pure response data, no header or such.

Comment: Can you clarify more? i am new at Objective-C. Im using a Asynchronous approach at this, and have implemented the delegate methods and using some of them. The thing is, i have a didRevieveData method that takes nsdata as a parameter. The problem is, i dont know how to get the response data from the request i send to the service.

So basicly i am sending a request to a service without knowing how to get the response printed out.